# What is the Ethernet Type II Protocol number for an ICMP echo request and reply?

Tags: ip, internet, tcpip

Hi I wanted to know what the Ethernet II Protocol number for an ICMP echo request and also for a ICMP echo reply?

Answer (score 10):

ICMP is an IP protocol not an Ethernet Protocol. It's protocol number is 1, for the rest see the [IANA assignments document](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/).

Comment: Just to add a little bit, echo-request is ICMP Type 8 and echo-reply is ICMP type 0

Comment: Sounds more like a little byte to me ;)

Comment: @Zypher nicely clarified.

Comment: In addition, the ICMP code number returned with the type can be invaluable in troubleshooting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol

Answer (score 2):

The Ethernet protocol number would be 0800, as for any IP frame.